# can not install vagrant percise32's box

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'll trying this command :

`vagrant init hashicorp/percise32 && vagrant up`

but this error happen

```
The box 'hashicorp/percise32' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/percise32"]
Error: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is complete valid syntax, you just had a misspell on the name

```
vagrant init hashicorp/precise32 && vagrant up
```

*note* precise32 vs percise32

`vagrant init hashicorp/precise32` creates a vagrantfile with the name of the box. When you'll run `vagrant up` from this Vagrantfile, vagrant will create the VM from the box referenced from the file, if it does not find it, it will download the box

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
vagrant box add hashicorp/precise32
```

and then try

```
vagrant init
```

You should have your box referenced in your vagrant file:

```
  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"

  # The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
  # doesn't already exist on the user's system.
  config.vm.box_url = "https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise32/versions/1.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box"
```

and then

```
vagrant up
```

if that doesnt help though not recomended try this on the first step :

`vagrant box add hashicorp/precise32 https://atlas.hashicorp.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise32/versions/1.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box`

Hope it helps

Comment: @Sudakatux, syntax is valid I edited my answer to explain `vagrant init hashicorp/precise32` creates a vagrantfile with the name of the box. When you'll run `vagrant up` from this Vagrantfile, vagrant will create the VM from the box referenced from the file, if it does not find it, it will download the box

Comment: also the name of the box must match, so if your box is named hashicorp/precise32, you must use this name in your Vagrantfile

Comment: Oh yes sorry im not using the same im using precise32 not hashicorp, thats why the mixup with the file, i edited my response to reflect what you are pointing out. Thank u.  and yes the syntax he is using is correct and there is a spell mistake